# Rewrite code to Bootstrap 3.3.7

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I was using Bootstrap incorrect, so therefore I am rewriting my code. I can understand that it is important to follow the structure: `container > row > col`. I am using cards, so when the viewport is under 768px the block elements will be cards. The demo can be seen here:

Before I used Bootstrap correct: [Before rewrite](http://vouzalis.dk/before-rewrite-to-bootstrap.html)

After I rewrite to correct Bootstrap: [After rewrite to bootstrap](http://vouzalis.dk/after-rewrite-to-bootstrap.html)

After I rewrite to correct use of Bootstrap the block elements is flying on top of eachother. As I see it - it is the class: `<div class="index-content">` there is causing this problem. If that class is below the `row` it is working, but if I set `<div class="index-content">` inside `<div class="col-sm-4">` the blocks are flying around.

Does anybody knows how I can solve this problem?

**My original code there was working were looking like this:**

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="index-content">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="col-sm-4 small-padding right bottom">
                <div class="card">
                    <img src="https://image.ibb.co/iiWA2T/bmw_1.jpg"></img>
                    <div class="card-content">
                        <h4>BMW NEW MODELS</h4>
                        <a href="#" class="blue-button">Read More</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-8 small-padding left">
                <div class="card">
                    <img src="https://image.ibb.co/nJ97Go/bmw.jpg"></img>
                    <div class="card-content">
                        <h4>BMW NEW MODELS</h4>
                        <!-- <p>Brødtekst</p> -->
                        <a href="#" class="blue-button">Read More</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**After rewrite to correct Bootstrap:**

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-4 small-padding right bottom">
            <div class="index-content">
                <div class="card">
                    <img src="https://image.ibb.co/iiWA2T/bmw_1.jpg"></img>
                    <div class="card-content">
                        <h4>BMW NEW MODELS</h4>
                        <a href="#" class="blue-button">Read More</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-8 small-padding left">
                <div class="card">
                    <img src="https://image.ibb.co/nJ97Go/bmw.jpg"></img>
                    <div class="card-content">
                        <h4>BMW NEW MODELS</h4>
                        <!-- <p>Brødtekst</p> -->
                        <a href="#" class="blue-button">Read More</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<style>
      /* Card and Button */
    .index-content a:hover {
      color: black;
      text-decoration: none;
    }

    .index-content {
      /*margin-bottom: 20px;*/
      /*padding: 50px 0px;*/
    }

    .index-content .row {
      margin-top: 20px;
    }

    .index-content a {
      color: black;
    }

    .index-content .card {
      background-color: #FFFFFF;
      padding: 0;
      -webkit-border-radius: 4px;
      -moz-border-radius: 4px;
      border-radius: 4px;
      box-shadow: 0 4px 5px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.14), 0 1px 10px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12), 0 2px 4px -1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
    }

    .index-content .card:hover {
      box-shadow: 0 16px 24px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.14), 0 6px 30px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12), 0 8px 10px -5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
      color: black;
    }

    .index-content .card img {
      width: 100%;
      border-top-left-radius: 4px;
      border-top-right-radius: 4px;
      height: 350px;

    }

    .index-content .card h4 {
      margin: 20px;
    }

    .index-content .card p {
      margin: 20px;
      opacity: 0.65;
    }

    .index-content .blue-button {
      width: 100px;
      -webkit-transition: background-color 1s, color 1s;
      /* For Safari 3.1 to 6.0 */
      transition: background-color 1s, color 1s;
      min-height: 20px;
      background-color: #002E5B;
      color: #ffffff;
      border-radius: 4px;
      text-align: center;
      font-weight: lighter;
      margin: 0px 20px 15px 20px;
      padding: 5px 0px;
      display: inline-block;
    }

    .index-content .blue-button:hover {
      background-color: #dadada;
      color: #002E5B;
    }

    @media (max-width: 768px) {
      .index-content .col-lg-4 {
        margin-top: 20px;
      }
    }

    @media (min-width: 768px) {
      .card {
        position: relative;
      }
      .card-content {
        position: absolute;
        bottom: 0;
        width: 100%;
        background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
      }
      .card-content h4,
      .card-content p {
        color: white;
        width: 100%;
        float: left;
        margin: 0 0 5px;
      }
      .card-content a {
        float: right;
      }
      .index-content .card h4,
      .index-content .card p {
        padding: 15px 20px;
        margin: 0;
      }
      .index-content .card p {
        padding: 0 20px 15px;
        margin: 0;
      }
    }

    /* GRID ELEMENTS */
        /* Set width between block elements */
        .small-padding.top {
           padding-top:10px;
        }

        .small-padding.bottom {
            padding-bottom:10px;
        } 
        .small-padding.left {
            padding-left:5px;
        }

        .small-padding.right {
            padding-right:5px;
        }
        /* Media quries */
        @media only screen and (max-width: 768px) {
            .small-padding.bottom {
            padding-bottom:10px;
        } 

        }
        @media only screen and (max-width: 768px) {

        .row [class*="col-"] {
          padding-left: 5px;
          padding-right: 5px;
      }

        }
    </style>
```

Comment: Would you mind sharing the custom CSS that may interfere with the provided code?

Comment: Sorry yes. I have posted the CSS now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-4">
        <div class="index-content">
            <div class="card">
                <img src="https://image.ibb.co/iiWA2T/bmw_1.jpg">
                <div class="card-content">
                    <h4>BMW NEW MODELS</h4>
                    <a href="#" class="blue-button">Read More</a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-8">
        <div class="card">
            <img src="https://image.ibb.co/nJ97Go/bmw.jpg" style="width: 100%;">
            <div class="card-content">
                <h4>BMW NEW MODELS</h4>
                <!-- <p>Brødtekst</p> -->
                <a href="#" class="blue-button">Read More</a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. That seems to solve some of the problem. But how can I keep the 2 pictures align with eachother all the way through the viewports. That should be 350px high.

Comment: I can see the button is also not working on the col-sm-8 with this solution and the gradient dark color under the text and button.

Comment: It was just missing `<div class="index-content">` inside the `col-sm-8`. Working now.